# How to add Accept/Deny button to a submission bot discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord applications bot for members to apply for moderator. However, I am not able to add the Accept/Reject buttons to the embed. Here is the bot source code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord import app_commands

TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN'
GUILD = 'GUILD NAME'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client) #For slash command

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to: \n {guild.name}')

@tree.command(name='apply', description='apply', guild=discord.Object(id = 000000))
async def commandno1(interaction:discord.Interaction, name:str, reason:str, exp:str):
     emb = discord.Embed(title='Mod App', description=f'Name: {name} \n Reason: {reason} \n exp:{exp}')
     emb.set_author(name='Submitted by {interaction.user}')
     channel = client.fetch_channel(00000000000)  #to send it to the admin for review
     await channel.send(embed=emb)
     await interaction.response.send_message('App submitted', ephemeral=True)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I was trying to get 2 buttons below the embed. One to accept, other to deny.
Please let me know how to add those buttons.

( It should be those clickable buttons, not reactions )

Also, once a button is clicked, I need to log it to a channel, so let me know how to do that as well. Thank you.

- Python 3.11 IDLE
- discord.client()
- app_commands.commandTree()
- discord.py 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

It goes like this
Add your button functions under there

````
import discord
from discord import commands

client = commands.Client()

@tree.command(name='apply', description='apply', guild=discord.Object(id = 000000))
async def commandno1(interaction:discord.Interaction, name:str, reason:str, exp:str):
     emb = discord.Embed(title='Mod App', description=f'Name: {name} \n Reason: {reason} \n exp:{exp}')
     emb.set_author(name='Submitted by {interaction.user}')
     b1 = discord.ui.Button(label='Accept', style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
     b1 = discord.ui.Button(label='Reject', style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
     view = discord.ui.View()
     view.add_item(b1)
     view.add_item(b2)
     channel = client.fetch_channel(00000000000)  #to send it to the admin for review

  
     async def b1_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
        #add your function
     async def b2_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
        #add your function
        ```

     b1.callback = b1_callback
     b2.callback = b2_callback
     await channel.send(embed=emb, view=view)
     await interaction.response.send_message('App submitted', ephemeral=True)
````

And for logging use this to send message

```
channel = client.fetch_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(f"message")
```